# md5sum - No properly formatted md5 checksum lines found

Tags: md5, md5sum, md5-file

I created a checksum file on a windows machine to verify on a linux machine.

Before I transferred the file over I ran dos2unix on windows to get rid of the nasty windows features.

The content of the file currently looks like this:

```
79ac8d043dc8739f661c45cc33fc07ac ReadMe.txt
```

This gave me the first error of wrong format. I then looked up the format and found I needed two spaces for md5sum to work so I transformed it on the linux machine using `sed 's_ _  _g'`.

This gave me an md5 content that looks like this:

```
79ac8d043dc8739f661c45cc33fc07ac  ReadMe.txt
```

This still gives me the wrong format error. What am I doing wrong?

If this is any help, this is the exact error I get:

```
md5sum -c output2.md5
md5sum: output2.md5: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found
```

Please send help.
Julian

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the dos encoding, dos2unix on windows apearently did not work properly.

using dos2unix on the linux machine solved the problem.